# MLE based on AR(1) process use the delta method

Tags: statistics, convergence-divergence

We have an AR(1) process given by:
 $X_t=\rho X_{t-1}+\epsilon_t$  t=1,……..,T+h

where $\epsilon_t~N(0,\sigma^2)$, t=1,2…., are independent.
The intial value $X_0$ is fixed and known we asume absolute value of  $\rho<1$.
Let $\hat{p}_T$ denote the MLE of  $\rho$ based on $X_0,……,X_T.$

Then  $\sqrt{T}( \hat{p}_T-\rho)$ $\overset{D} \to$ $N(0,1-\rho^2)$ as T$\to\infty$.

Use the delta method to show that
$ \sqrt{T}( \hat{\rho}^h_T-\rho^h)$ $\overset{D} \to$ $N(0,(1-\rho^2)(hp^{h-1})^2)$ as T$\to\infty$.

I have not been able to find any good approach for the delta method in this case can anyone help with a link of the delta method in this case or any other hints is really appreciated.

Best Regards Christian Skjøth

Answer (score 1):

Let $g(\hat{\phi})=\hat{\phi}^k$. Seeing that $g'(\hat{\phi})=k\hat{\phi}^{k-1}$, and that $g(\phi)=\phi^k$, the delta method: 
    $$ 
 \sqrt{t}(g(\hat{\phi}) - g(\phi))\rightarrow N(0,(1-\phi)^2(k\hat{\phi}^{k-1})^2)
 $$